# Prevent lifting Files htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Now I finished create a simple system upload files with php but i need a help please and this my order :
I want a solution to block upload **.htaccess** file in my upload
website.
and other files (**.css** **.php .html** ...).

**PHP CODE**

```
set_time_limit(0);
require("connect.php");
if (isset($_FILES['upload_file'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'] as $count=>$upload_file) {
        if (!empty($_FILES['image']['error'][$count])) {
            return false; 
        }
        if (!empty($upload_file)&&is_uploaded_file($upload_file)) {
            $charset="AHfgG15Ds10MZD58N";
            $code='';
            $length=15;
            for ($i=0; $i<=$length; $i++) {
                $rand=rand()%strlen($charset);
                $tmp=substr($charset,$rand,1);
                $code.=$tmp;
            }

            $query=mysql_query("SELECT `code` FROM `files`  WHERE `code`='$code'") or die(mysql_error());
            $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);

            while ($numrows!=0) {
                $code='';
                for ($i=0; $i<=$length; $i++) {
                    $rand=rand()%strlen($charset);
                    $tmp=substr($charset,$rand,1);
                    $code.=$tmp;
                }
                $query=mysql_query("SELECT `code` FROM `files`  WHERE `code`='$code'");
                $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
            }

            mkdir("upload/$code/");

            $name=$_FILES['upload_file']['name'][$count];
            $type=$_FILES['upload_file']['type'][$count];
            $size=$_FILES['upload_file']['size'][$count];
            $site_url=('http://localhost');
            $url= ("$site_url/download.php?file=$code");
            mysql_query("SET NAME utf8 ");
            $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO files VALUES ('','$name','$code','$type','$size','$url')");
            $url=urlencode($name);
            $upload=move_uploaded_file($upload_file,"upload/$code/".$name);
            if ($upload) { ?>
                <table>
                <tr>
                <td><h3>File name</h3></td><td><h3>File Link</h3></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo"$name"; ?></td><td> <?php echo"<a href='http://localhost/downoald.php?file=$code' target='_blanck'>http://localhost/downoald.php?file=$code</a>"; ?></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            <?php } else { ?>
                No file selected
            <?php }
             } else {
  echo "Invalid file";
        }
}
}
```

**Please edit this code In order me needs.**

Comment: the way you use mysql_query is highly problematic for sql injections through the filename. consider using prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

you could do sth like

```
// the list of unallowed file endings, can be extended easily by your needs
$disallow = array(
  'php',
  '.htaccess',
);
// loop over all disallowed file extensions and name the current one needle
foreach ($disallow as $needle) {

  // if the given filename ($name) ends in the current needle we print and error and stop the processing.
  if (substr($name, -strlen($needle)) === $needle) {
    echo "Invalid file extension";
    exit();
  }
}
```